# Calling method through nextFocusForward - Android

Tags: java, android, datepicker, onclick, android-edittext

I'm trying to implement a registration page with very natural flow, and am running into some difficulty with nextFocusForward. Ideally, after typing in the email and pressing "Next" on the keyboard, the datepicker for birthday would show up, but displaying the datepicker is a method call in the java code. Activating the datepicker is done by a TextView onClick method.

Is there a way to call a method or simulate a click (or call the revealDatepicker method) when "Next" is hit on the keyboard?

Relevant code:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:background="@drawable/email_address_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:nextFocusForward="@+id/datePickerButton"/>

<TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:text="Set Birthdate"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/datePickerButton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="revealDatepicker"
            android:background="@drawable/birthday_background"/>
```

Comment: did you try to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean) or focusable